# Scapy not capturing any packets

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

Ok so I am making a program that is supposed to capture packets, the program used to work just fine, but now for some reason it just stopped working.

This is not my actual code, however it is having the same problem as my actual code:

```
from scapy.all import *
counter = 0
def action(packet):
   global counter
   counter += 1
   return 'Packet #{}: {} ==> {}'.format(counter, packet[0][1].src, packet[0][1].dst)

sniff(filter="ip", prn=action)
```

Once again, this used to work just fine, but now it doesnt. It captures a packet very rarely, and when it does capture packets it looks like this:
[image]

It seems like it is capturing from the wrong source or something, but I ain't a computer genius so I am probably wrong. Thank you if you are able to answer this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to specify an interface: `sniff([...], iface=<iface>)`. By default, `sniff()` will only capture packets from the default interface (see `conf.iface` value).

Under Windows, the `IFACES` variable contains all the interfaces usable by Scapy.

Comment: What are the interfaces that I can sniff?

Comment: Also I thought by default it sniffs every interface